# "windowSoftInputMode=stateHidden" doesn't work for Instant Run

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, instant

Recently I've found that despite `windowSoftInputMode=stateHidden` the soft keyboard appears at start of activity when the app is run from Google Play store as Instant Run (Try Now), however the Instant Run compilation works all right when installed on device through ADB.

Is there a way to get around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find anything better than set all EditText views not focusable and then focusable again. Something like that:

```
if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.contains("instant")) {
   final View myEditTextView = findViewById(R.id.myEditTextViewId);
   myEditTextView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
   myEditTextView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          myEditTextView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
      }
   }, 500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

run below command:

```
npm i cordova-plugin-multidex
```

which adds the multidex flag to Android builds by amending the AndroidManifest.xml generated by Cordova

Here is a [ref about multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex)

Comment: Mine is not a multidex app and I will do my best to avoid multidex. :)  Certainly a sandbox issue, however I don't see how this it be related to single- or multi-dex.

Comment: sorry I posted wrong place, this is an answer for another question :)